# Birt report Parameter allow multiple value

Tags: java, birt

I have created a parameter type listbox where I have allowed to select multiple values. I want to use this parameter in the dataset. I used to accpet values in other dataset with StoredProcdureName(?,?) as parameter to SP. The problem with this filter is that it shows Selection if I select one or more values, but while passing to sp it sends only one value. How can I handle this?

Comment: post the code, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should at least post your stored procedure, such that we can see how this parameter is used.  Multi-value parameters are processed by BIRT as java arrays, which is not a data type recognized by stored routines. This is why you only get the first item.

Therefore assuming this parameter is a SQL filter in a "IN" clause, we need to pass it to the stored procedure as a comma-separated String.

Declare your **dataset** parameter as String, and don't link it to a **report** parameter but set a default value expression based on the report parameter instead. In this example "myMultivalueParam" represents a numeric field in your database:

```
params["myMultivalueParam"].value.join(",");
```

If "myMultivalueParam" represents a String we need to add quotes:

```
params["myMultivalueParam"].value.join("','");
```

Then use this comma-separated string in your stored procedure.

Comment: I have called Stored procedure like {call usp_rpt_PartnerLoginReport(?)} And Used ListBox with multiselect option. It is accepting multiple values but while passing to sp it passes only first value and i have handled in sp to select multivalue.